# SQL select groups with minimum sizes

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, group-by

I didn't manage to find an answer for this, so

basically how do you perform a SQL query on a dataset to first group the rows based on a few columns and then select/filter only the groups with more rows than a specified size.

Heres is an example of what I am trying to achieve with a pandas dataframe:

```
df.groupby([cols_to_group]).filter(lambda x: len(x) > minimum_group_size)
```

How can you perform this with SQL query?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Also: [edit] your question and add the table definitions as `create table` statements, some sample data and the expected output based on that data.

Comment: Take a look to Having: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name PostgreSQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a solution can be this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *
        , COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY cols_to_group) as cnt  -- cnt is length of each group
    FROM yourTable) t
WHERE t.cnt > minimum_group_size;
```

Comment: to get groups with minimum size, I will need `WHERE tt.cnt > size;` instead of `WHERE tt.rn = 1;`?